# Issue with serializer and api

Tags: django, api

My problem is that I want to to get category.name instead of category.id in api.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

 
 class Meta:
     model = models.Post
     fields = ['id', 'title', 'content', 'category', 'img', 'date_posted']
```

But when I adding it, there disappears option in POST method to set category.  For api view I use
`generics.ListCreateAPIView`

```
  def getCategory(self,obj):
       return obj.category.name

  category = serializers.SerializerMethodField("getCategory")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) that takes the `name` of the `Category` as data:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='name',
        queryset=Category.objects.all()
    )
 
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'content', 'category', 'img', 'date_posted']
```

The advantage of this is that this works *bi-directional*: if the `name` of a category is `unique=True`, then that means you can also use the `PostSerializer` to create a `Post` and specify the `name` of the category in the POST request.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in the following way

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   category_name = serializer.SerializerMethodField()
 
   class Meta:
       model = models.Post
       fields = ['id', 'title', 'content', 'category', 'img', 
       'date_posted','category_name ']

   def get_category_name(self,obj):
        return obj.category.name
```